# capture log of ufsdump when backup to stdout

Tags: logs, solaris, stdout, stderr

I am backing a file system with ufsdump.
In order to gain space in the remote file system I backup to stdout then pipe the output to compress. I find is more efficient that backuping up and then running gzip.

so basically i have this command:

```
/usr/sbin/ufsdump 0uf - / | compress -c -v > /backup/$HOST/root-$DATE-full.dump.Z
```

I would like to save the diagnostic information of ufsdump to a file for monitoring and checking out if the dump completed successfully. but this does not seem to be possible with the command above? please note that if I backup to a file instead of standard output i can capture the diagnostics of ufsdump without problem.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would solve the problem:

`ufsdump 0uf - / 2>/backup/logs/root-08.12.2014.log | gzip -v > /backup/root-08-12.14-full.dump.gz`

I found it here: 
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1339437